# Number of rows per page SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Our server team resource member uploaded the SSRS reports from sql reporting server 2005 to sql reporting service 2008 R2 server. While I am testing , I see one difference, number of pages coming the 2008 r2 server is more than the 2005 servers. For example,  I got 20 pages in the sql 2005 server and 30 pages in sql 2008 r2 servers. Is it a setting or anything I am missing or anything needs to be adjusted?

Also I compared both the reports, both reports have same data. The only difference I see is less number of rows per page on 2008 r2 servers . Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check size properties on both of your reports like:

1. Page size and orientation.
2. Page margins.
3. Text size on the tablix.
4. Spacing between and in tablix cells.

Other than these I'm not too sure.

I'm quite intrigued in your issue. Good luck!